# Multicluster ingress with istio and GKE

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, istio

I have this link guide:

> https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/istio-samples/tree/master/multicluster-ingress

When i came to 6 phase i got stuck
on ingress process,
with:

```
"Error syncing to GCP: error running load balancer syncing routine: loadbalancer zq3myjrv-istio-system-zoneprinter-ii1mnlqr does not exist: googleapi: Error 400: Invalid value for field 'resource.IPAddress': 'X.X.X.X'. Specified IP address is in-use and would result in a conflict., invalid"
```

i tried it with istio 1.5.0 \ 4 \ 9.
one of istio ingress work with the ip address and the other stuck with this massage.
Someone with any experience with that?
maybe someone have any solutions?
tnx.

Comment: seems pretty simple. can't find the load balancer. and the load balancer seems to not getting created because there is an IP address conflict. Might be timing issue. do you have an `Ingress` object created? what's it state? to try something, check in GCP if you have a static IP address with the name `zoneprinter-ip`. If you do, comment out the gcloud line from `6-mci.sh` script, and try again. remove also the `Ingress` object from the cluster, if it exists.

Comment: ya, ingress created, the "issue message" is from the ingress,
one of the istio ingressgateway used the name ip and the other throw error..
also the LB created.
all the process went ok, all the services and ingress created.
about 6-mci,
if i commented the gcloud command that means that ingress doesn't knew for who to create the ingress.

Comment: you shouldn't have more then one LB. It is one HTTP (Global) load balancer for all three clusters. If your `istio-ingressgateway` service is of `LoadBalancer` type service, it doesn't seem to be the right configuration.

Comment: all this process works well without istio system, but my services works with it
so. i have istio on my cluster..
and for all each service it's create a new LB. (without istio)

Comment: yes, it seems it does have one LB for each cluster as well, which is a waste of resource, under my point of view, but the reserved IP address should go for the HTTP load balancer. Is the static IP assigned to one of the load balancers of `istio-ingressgateway`?

Comment: about commenting out the gcloud line, it is only creating the static IP address. If you already have it, you don't really need it.